# Server Side Includes - class="active" for menu

Tags: html, ssi

Do many people use Server Side Includes?  Does anyone know if they are SEO safe, do most search engines treat them the same as basic .htm pages?

Firstly they do make maintaining a common menu and quick links pane much easier than copy and pasting to each page.

Also what about using an SSI #if, or some other method, to include class="active" for the active page in the menu.  Has anyone used SSI for this or are there any drawbacks that I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

> Do many people use Server Side Includes?

Not many these days, they have been largely superseded by other technologies.

> Does anyone know if they are SEO safe, do most search engines treat them the same as basic .htm pages?

Completely. They are server side.

> Firstly they do make maintaining a common menu and quick links pane much easier than copy and pasting to each page.

Yes. I'd still rather use a decent template engine though.

> Also what about using an SSI #if, or some other method, to include class="active" for the active page in the menu. Has anyone used SSI for this or are there any drawbacks that I am missing.

It is possible, but a bit verbose.